# PHP Save bind_result field in Comma Separated Value then Insert in Another Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am a Newbie. I am trying to get all the `users_id` from `users` table in a comma separated value like `1001,1002,1003 etc` then insert them as a comma separated value directly in `tmpOrder` table `sq_id` column. So far I have written below code but it is not inserting comma separated value. If I take foreach loop then it inserts an individual row for each `user_id` but I need to insert a single row with all the comma separated id's in  `sq_id` column

```
 $sql="SELECT users.id as user_id,age FROM users";

 $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);                 
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($data[0], $data[1]);

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   echo $data[0];
 }

 $stmt1 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tmpOrder(id,sq_id) 
 VALUES ($id,implode(',',$data[0]");

 $stmt1->execute();
```

Comment: you did not define $data anywhere, how you are getting data in $data variable

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single query, using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to generate a comma separated list from `users` and `INSERT` that directly into `tmpOrder` using an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tmpOrder(id, sq_id)
        SELECT ?, GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
        FROM users";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helpful...

```
INSERT 
INTO tmpOrder(id,sq_id) 
VALUES ( 
  $id,
  ( 
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(users.id SEPARATOR ',') 
    FROM
      users
  )
)
```